# Write an Or filter in Ember

Tags: javascript, database, ember.js, ember-data

I want to write an `Or` filter in Ember. The filter that I want to implement is as follows:

```
(end_date <= filter_end_date && end_date >= filter_start_date) || (start_date >= filter_start_date && start_date <= filter_end_date) || (start_date <= filter_start_date && end_date >= filter_end_date)
```

I am collecting all the filters together and then passing it while sending the query:

```
filterOptions: [
    {
      name : 'state',
      op   : 'eq',
      val  : 'published'
    }
  ]
```

Query is as follows:

```
return this.get('store').query('event', {
      sort   : 'starts-at',
      filter : filterOptions
    });
```

I went through the docs but didn't find anything. What is best way to model this filter?

Comment: Um, If you pass the filter to the server you have to filter on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, @jelhan is correct. We are using Flask-REST-JSONAPI as the filtering system. The filtering system is completely related to the data layer used by the ResourceList manager. So, I used https://flask-rest-jsonapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filtering.html as a reference and wrote the filter as follows :

```
dateFilterWithEndDate: computed('start_date', 'end_date', function() {
    return EmberObject.create(
      {
        or:
          [
            {
              and: [
                {
                  name : 'starts-at',
                  op   : 'ge',
                  val  : this.get('start_date')
                },
                {
                  name : 'starts-at',
                  op   : 'le',
                  val  : this.get('end_date')
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              and: [
                {
                  name : 'ends-at',
                  op   : 'ge',
                  val  : this.get('start_date')
                },
                {
                  name : 'ends-at',
                  op   : 'le',
                  val  : this.get('end_date')
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              and: [
                {
                  name : 'starts-at',
                  op   : 'le',
                  val  : this.get('start_date')
                },
                {
                  name : 'ends-at',
                  op   : 'ge',
                  val  : this.get('end_date')
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
      }

    );
  }),

  dateFilterBasic: computed('start_date', function() {
    return EmberObject.create(
      {
        or: [
          {
            name : 'starts-at',
            op   : 'ge',
            val  : this.get('start_date')
          },
          {
            name : 'ends-at',
            op   : 'ge',
            val  : this.get('start_date')
          }
        ]
      }
    );
  }),
```

I add this to the `filter` parameter in the query method as follows:

```
    if (endDate) {
      filterOptions.pushObject(this.get('dateFilterWithEndDate'));
    } else {
      filterOptions.pushObject(this.get('dateFilterBasic'));
    }

    return this.get('store').query('event', {
      sort   : 'starts-at',
      filter : filterOptions
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

What your are asking for is a filtering strategy used by your REST API. This is not specific to ember.js. The `store` service, which `query` method you are using, is provided by ember-data. Ember-data is the default persistence layer for ember and included by default blueprints of ember-cli into a new project.

By default ember-data is implementing the [JSON API specification](http://jsonapi.org/). The specification registers the `filter` query parameter for filtering but is agnostic about the used filtering strategy:

> Note: JSON API is agnostic about the strategies supported by a server. The filter query parameter can be used as the basis for any number of filtering strategies. ([Source](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-filtering))

There is only a recommendation for filtering, which addresses filtering by the ID of a associated record:

> It’s recommended that servers that wish to support filtering of a
>   resource collection based upon associations do so by allowing query
>   parameters that combine filter with the association name.
>
> For example, the following is a request for all comments associated
>   with a particular post:
>
> GET /comments?filter[post]=1 HTTP/1.1
>
> [Source](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#filtering)

The only filtering strategy build into ember-data is about filtering by multiple IDs of the requested resource. It's used if build-in JSONAPIAdapter is used and [`coalesceFindRequests` option](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter/properties/coalesceFindRequests?anchor=coalesceFindRequests) is `true`. It defaults to `false`. In that case ember-data coalesces multiple requests for specific records of one resource into one GET query to avoid multiple queries being fired. It's using the `filter` query parameter together with the property used for filtering (`id`) wrapped in square brackets and a comma separated list of IDs. E.g. a query of `/posts` endpoint for posts with ID 1 and 2 would look like: `GET /posts?filter[id]=1,2`.

So to put it together all of the existing pieces are only about filtering by IDs of (associated) resources.

There is a good reason JSON API specification is agnostic about filtering strategy: a well fitting filtering strategy is highly application specific. Supporting the full power of SQL on REST APIs might add big performance issues to API.

However there are quite a lot complex filtering strategies, which could be implemented and fitting well with the recommendation in JSON API and `coalesceFindRequests` feature of ember-data.

For example the [filtering syntax used by OpenStack](https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/api-wg/guidelines/pagination_filter_sort.html#filtering) could be adopted. That one allows to add operators separated from value by a colon to the filter. With that one a query to request all posts published after January 1, 2018 would look like: `GET /posts?filter[published-at]=gt:2018-01-01`. Please note that I've also made the assumption to use camel-cased field names and ISO-8601 date strings. However this syntax does not support an `or` operator. There are some arguments for not putting complexity of an `or` operator to REST API filtering strategies. You could easily have that option by using separated queries and merging the returned collections.

An even more complex filtering strategy is the [Resource Query Language (RQL)](https://github.com/persvr/rql). That one separates operator and value by an equal sign. So the request used as example above would look like: `GET /posts?filter[published-at]=gt=2018-01-01` RQL also supports `or` operator using paranthesis to group expressions separated by vertical bars. A query for posts published after January 1 2018 but before February 1 2018 would look like: `GET /posts?(filter[published-at]=gt=2018-01-01|filter[published-at]=lt=2018-02-01)` However one could argue that this not a very common syntax for query parameters and may cause issues with web servers, caches, proxies etc.

Since ember-data passes the second argument of [`store.query()`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.Store/methods/query?anchor=query) directly forward to [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) as `data` setting, you are totally free to choose a filtering strategy based on your application needs.